# Touch device disable element hover

Tags: css, mobile

this could be a question a bit strange.
When I'm on mobile and i have an hover, it remains in its hover state of until I click on another item, I'd like to delete the hover after some time or when the page is scrolled.
Any advice.

Comment: Why would you use :hover in your mobile version? Use media queries for mobile devices and leave out the hover

Comment: yes, I have thumbs that display titles when hovered, I would like this way, if I find a way to "unbind" hover state.

Comment: How is the hover working to begin with? Are you using the built in CSS :hover or are you using some JS code to make the hover work?

Comment: I have 2 nested elems, the child is hidden, when hover the parent the child is display block and css3 animation, this way i have a nice mobile fake hover... first touch hover, second touch link. I'ma search something to get back when page is scrolled (I know it's weird but I'm looking for a solution to maintain a minimal design even on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in this case. If you want to target the user on desktop:

```
@media screen { /* hover styles here */ }
```

and if you want to target mobile device, for example ipad you can use this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* non-hover styles here */
}
```

Comment: No sorry, maybe I did not explain, I do not mean that. Thank you anyway.